# Swagger Python Flask server sluggish over HTTPS

Tags: python, flask, https, swagger, openapi

I have a swagger openapi v3 python flask generated REST API server. 
I have just added HTTPS support to it and have used a self signed cert as follows.

```
CERT = '/cert/my-cert.pem'
KEY = '/cert/my-key.pem'

def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
    app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'My API'}, pythonic_params=True)
    CORS(app.app)
    app.run(port=7000, debug=True, ssl_context=(CERT, KEY))
```

I assess the swagger UI as follows:
    https://10.190.111.23:7000/ui/

I notice that very often there is a very long response time when the swagger UI loads in the web browser and lots of times it does not load at all and simply times out.
If I **do not** use HTTPS then it loads fine every time.

Why could this be?

Comment: If you suspect TLS problems, observe the request a few times with `curl -v --insecure https://10.190.111.23:7000/ui/`.  The `--insecure` arg ignores the self_signed_cert warning.  This may lend further clues to why this is hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The solution was:

1. remove the password from the private key: openssl rsa -in key-decrypt.pem -outform PEM -out key.pem
2. use the original https port=443